# Django REST framework - filtering against query params with date and string parameter

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I created my "API" using REST framework, now trying to do filtering for it. That's how my models.py look for Schedule model.

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    travel_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to filter `departure` and `travel_date_time` on query parameters. Basically field `departure` comes from following models.

```
class BusCompanyRoute(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

and route is linked with 'Route' model in following way

```
class Route(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='route_destiantion'
    )
    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Route'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Routes'
```

and Location model is

```
class Location(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        validators=[validate_location_name],
        unique=True,
    )
```

I basically use usecases.py for my logic section so in my views.py file I have following code to get query paramters.

```
class BusCompanyTicketDetailView(generics.ListAPIView, BusCompanyMixin):
    serializer_class = serializers.TicketDetailResponseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        travel_date = (self.request.query_params.get('travel_date'))
        destination = (self.request.query_params.get('destination'))
        return usecases.ListBusCompanyTicketUseCase(
            bus_company=self.get_bus_company(),
            date=travel_date,
            destination=destination
        ).execute()
```

and my usecase file have following code.

```
class ListBusCompanyTicketUseCase(BaseUseCase):
    def __init__(self, bus_company: BusCompany, date: datetime, destination):
        self._bus_company = bus_company
        self._date = date
        self._destination = destination

        # print(datetime)

    def execute(self):
        self._factory()
        return self._schedules
    def _factory(self):
        self._schedules = Schedules.objects.filter(bus__bus_company=self._bus_company ,travel_date_time__date=self._date ,bus_company_route__route__destination=self._destination)
```

Finally my url with query parameter is as follows

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/ticket/bus-company/1037a4cc-ff38-4948-978a-5a7b92cb7a41/list?travel_date=2021-1-2&destination=florida
```

I was getting correct query only with travel_date_time but on adding destiantion I am getting error as

```
ValidationError at /api/v1/ticket/bus-company/1037a4cc-ff38-4948-978a-5a7b92cb7a41/list
['“florida” is not a valid UUID.']
```

what is wrong in query parameter urls or is my query wrong?

Comment: Is there a destination field missing from your Route model?

Comment: is `Destination` model if so add another filter criteria like `name`  in which actual name of the destination like florida is saved in `Destination` model e.g.`bus_company_route__route__destination__name=self._destination`

Comment: i updated question and added my Location model

Comment: thank you  added this `destination__name` got my query you may answer below for acceptance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Destination` model has property `name` therefore add another filter criteria `name` in filter query

```py
def _factory(self):
        self._schedules = Schedules.objects.filter(bus__bus_company=self._bus_company ,travel_date_time__date=self._date ,bus_company_route__route__destination__name=self._destination)
```